# Is this question ok? "What are the differences in..."

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, deleted-questions

I just came across this question, and thought that it seemed *very* open ended and hard to answer "correctly". Is it a good question for this site? If so, why? It is one of the highest voted questions on the site but in my opinion, it is not one of the strongest.

[What are the differences in punctuation between German and English?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/4/what-are-the-differences-in-punctuation-between-german-and-english)

Comment: I asked the question in my naïve belief that there were just a few differences. As toscho says, it would make a good community wiki. As of yet, though, there are only 3-4 unique differences listed in the answers.

Comment: No disrespect. I wouldn't have brought it up if the site wasn't only half a day old :)

Answer (score 4):

It is a good candidate for a community wiki. Besides that, it is a question most readers can learn from. Open questions aren’t bad automatically.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I guess it's not such a bad thing that there probably wont be one correct answer.